# How do I stabilize Raspberry Pi-3 Restarts on Inverter Change Over

Tags: raspbian, pi-3

I power my house with 2.4KVA Inverter while the Inverter is connected to the AC 230V Mains together with 1200Watts Solar panel.

I experience steady power supply except for when ever The AC Power goes off, before the Inverter will automatically change/switch to Solar Power, My Raspberry Pi 3 will restart while every other Electronic devices and Computers is stable. This also affects my TV decoder at times ;).

I tried using 5V 2A UPS/Power-bank like the ones attached on Picture

[image]

For the Pi-3 but still no success, same thing happens.

Do anyone know the best way to keep my Raspberry Pi-3 stable in such Power Fluctuation?

My AC adapter for the Pi-3 is 5V 2.5A. If I increase it to 5V 5A, is it going to be harmful to the Pi-3?

Comment: The 5A on the supply is referring to the maximum it can supply without the 5V dropping, the Pi will only draw as much current as it needs so shouldn't be a problem (as long as the 5v doesn't change).

Comment: @Roger Jones, Yesterday I changed to 5V 3A adapter and it seems to be stable. I am still watching to see how it goes for the next one week. I suspect the issue is likely to be the current.

Comment: Hello @ellooku, do you have updates on this? I have your same issue. thx!